# React Dev Tool showing components as single letters

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, inspector, react-devtools

Wondering if it is normal for React Dev Tool on Chrome to components as many single letters on inspection?

I am trying to inspect some websites to better understand how good companies structure and write their React code, but all I ever see is stuff like `<t> <y>`, etc.

Here is an image of what I'm seeing:

https://ibb.co/4gCx7DJ

Could someone explain why this is?

Comment: This is called [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) to reduce file sizes transmitted over the web and to a limited extent obfuscate the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applications in production minify there code to save network resources. Thus, when you inspect in the devtools you do not see the full component names. However the prop names and state should be visible.